# Placing a pop out message once function has finished

Tags: angularjs, node.js, strongloop

How can I place a pop out message like 'message sent successfully' once the function has finished running in this case (smsAll)?

## controller

```
    $scope.smsAll = function() {

        $scope.smsStatusZeroF2F = "";
        $scope.smsStatusMoreThanTenF2F = "";
        $scope.smsStatusBetween14F2F = "";

        if ($scope.isSMSzeroF2F) {
            $scope.smsZeroF2F();
        }

        if ($scope.isSMSmoreThanTenF2F) {
            $scope.smsMoreThanTenF2F();
        }

        if ($scope.isSMSBet14F2F) {
            $scope.smsBetween14F2F();
        }

        if ($scope.isSMSZeroPSL) {
            $scope.smsZeroPSL();
        }

        if ($scope.isSMStransAndsaas) {
            $scope.smsZeroTransOrSaasReport();
        }

    };
```

## report.html

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="smsAll()">Send SMS for selected</button>
```

Comment: Use any of notification libraries, ex. https://notifyjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not used some angular notify moduel?
Just like [this](http://cgross.github.io/angular-notify/demo/)
Source code is [here](https://github.com/cgross/angular-notify)

Or Install with Bower

```
bower install angular-notify --save
```

Add dist/angular-notify.js and dist/angular-notify.css to your index.html.

Add cgNotify as a module dependency for your module.

```
angular.module('your_app', ['cgNotify']);
```

usage:

```
function myController($scope,notify){  // <-- Inject notify

  notify('Your notification message'); // <-- Call notify with your message

  notify({ message:'My message', templateUrl:'my_template.html'} );

}
```